# Does the root node of a decision tree start with the Highest Gini and Entropy value?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I have doubts about the two most traditional methods of CART.
Which are the Gini Index and Entropy, are two methods that determine the feature that will be the root node of the tree and its entire division.

The lower the Entropy and the Gini Index, the better correct? because I will have a more homogeneous data set.

the second question is: Will the feature with the LARGEST Gini index or in the case of Entropy with the LARGEST entropy be the Features that will be the root of the tree? or should you start with the lowest value feature? (in either method)

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.